# How to RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST messages from android devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

I want to receive **Emergency cell Broadcasting messages** in my application. For this, I want permission **`RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST`**. And i have to import some android OS classes **`com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony`**. But I can't access those classes in my application. Please do help me out this problem or can anyone can tell me how to access android hidden OS functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a broadcast receiver class in manifest with following filters

```
<intent-filter android:priority="999<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED" /></intent-filter>       <intent-filter><action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.CB_RECEIVED" />
```

In the broadcast receiver class we will get the intent in following overrided method.

```
public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent) {
}
```

Extratct the "paramIntent" for getting the Cell Broadcast message.